# Программа на C# (1000-7)

Tags: c#

Написать код для вычисления(1000 - 7 ).
Результат каждого действия выводить в консоль с интервалом в 0.5 секунды.
Пример:

```
1000-7 = 993
993 - 7 = 986
```

И т.д (Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Целиком код за вас писать не будут. Какие у вас сложности?

Answer (score 2):

У Майкрософта есть на это практически готовый ответ (я только добавил логику вывода). Хоть иногда попытайтесь поднапрячься и попытаться поискать решения, а не бежать на форум и просить сделать всё за Вас. Тут зарегистрироваться сложнее и дольше, чем найти готовое решение.

```
 using System;
 using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static int oneThousand = 1000;
        static int currenValue = 0;
        static int increment = 3;
        static Timer halfSeconTimer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetTimer();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
            halfSeconTimer.Stop();
            halfSeconTimer.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
        }


        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            halfSeconTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
            halfSeconTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            halfSeconTimer.AutoReset = true;
            halfSeconTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (oneThousand > 2)
            {
                currenValue = oneThousand - increment;
                Console.WriteLine(oneThousand + " - " + increment + " = " + currenValue);
                oneThousand = currenValue;
            }
            else
            {
                halfSeconTimer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Добавлю изящное решение от @aepot

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1000; i > 2; i-=3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " - 3 = " + (i - 3));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычный цикл `for` и `Thread.Sleep(500)` - не модно? )

Comment: Я написал, что скопипастил код с сайта майкрософта, если Вы хотите помочь ТСу модным кодом, то милости просим.

Comment: Ща, только найду кнопку "Ответить" :)

Comment: Хотите я в свой допишу?))

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Поставил вам плюсик.

Comment: Вот так вот, "приговорённый" заранее вопрос получил сразу 2 решения))